# Dynamically add members to action - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to perform a loop action to edit same property with its specific value on multiple controls.

Something like:

```
Dim action as action
action.add(control1)
action.add(control2)
action.add(control3)
action.run
```

Then the action will perform something like this:

```
For each ctrl as control in action.controls
ctrl.text = ctrl.text & "another value"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating new tasks of the same action by calling it with different controls. Even better than I wanted to.